# Calling Servlet using Ajax call in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am calling Servlet through Ajax Call if I Run this code in **Mozilla FireFox** its working fine but If I run my code in **Internet Explorer 8** its not working.Please Could any one help me.thanks.

My code:

```
function getXMLObject()  //XML OBJECT
{
    var xmlHttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return xmlHttp;  // Mandatory Statement returning the ajax object created
}
var xmlhttp = new getXMLObject();

function HomeWorkajaxFunction(param)
{
    if (xmlhttp) {
        var param1 = document.getElementById("selectError3").value;
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "SubjectServlet?sec=" + param + "&gdid=" + param1, true); //gettime will be the servlet name
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse1;
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlhttp.send(null);                   
    }
}

function handleServerResponse1() {
    // alert("11");
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {                      
            document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

        }
        else {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can't u use jquery.ajax(), its much easier than the above plainful code ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_get

Comment: yes but They already Implemented in long back I dont have any rights to change this code.this ajax call is not working on internet-explorer8

Comment: aren't u getting dat alert(11) in IE?

Comment: no alert is not comming I tried even its not calling that function

Comment: did u tried running this code in IE in compactbilty mode?

Comment: IE compactbilty mode means

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47378/discussion-between-arvind-and-venkatesh)